# Jquery selecting children but not parent

Tags: jquery, parent-child

http://jsfiddle.net/xfPxp/

Basically Trying to create a multi-tiered slide-down click menu,
I've gotten the sub menus to slideDown, but I can't figure out how to stop the
parent from slideUp-ing when I click on the children. Thanks for any help!

Html Code ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!--Nav Menu 1-->

<ul class="make">Club Car
    <ul class="model" style="display: none">Precedent
        <ul class="product" style="display: none">Brush Guard</ul>
        <ul class="product" style="display: none">Lift Kits</ul>
    </ul>

    <ul class="model" style="display: none">DS
        <ul class="product" style="display: none">Brush Guard</ul>
        <ul class="product" style="display: none">Lift Kits</ul>
    </ul>
</ul>

<!--- Nav Menu 2-->

<ul class="make">E-Z-Go
    <ul class="model" style="display: none">TXT
        <ul class="product" style="display:none">Brush Guard</ul>
        <ul class="product" style="display:none">Lift Kits</ul>
    </ul>

    <ul class="model" style="display: none">RXV
        <ul class="product" style="display:none">Brush Guard</ul>
        <ul class="product" style="display:none">Lift Kits</ul>
    </ul>
```

Jquery Script --------------------------------------------------

```
<script>
$("ul.make").click(function () {
        if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
        }
});
$("ul.model").click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
    }
    else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.stopPropagation` on `event` that you pass into your functions:

```
$("ul.make").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
    }
});

$("ul.model").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xfPxp/1/

Comment: This was an incredibly easy fix. I did an earlier version where I gave every sub-tree its own unique ID and wrote up a whole butt-load of script to address each line individually. This'll keep it way cleaner. Thankyou!

Comment: No problem, in short, `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up to the parents, so you're actually able to capture the element clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You just had to add event.stopPropagation to your functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/9hQz8/

Your click events were bubbling up to the other function.

```
$("ul.make").click(function (event) {
    alert("make " + this.tagName + " " + this.className);
            if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
                $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
            }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$("ul.model").click(function (event) {
    alert("make " + this.tagName + " " + this.className);
        if ($(this).children('ul').is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp("fast");
        }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```